# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'paypal_form' of null

Tags: javascript

So I am getting the following error on my site:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'paypal_form' of null
```

Here is the problem section:

```
success:function(data){
            if(typeof(data.paypal_form)!=null)
            {
```

Could someone tell me how to fix the type error?

Comment: Sounds like data is null. Can't tell you why without seeing more code.

Comment: you are receiving response as null, so `data.paypal_form` cant be executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
success:function(data){
if(!data)
{
console.log("data is null");
return;
}
if(!data.paypal_form)
{
console.log("data.paypal_form is null");
return;
}
if(typeof(data.paypal_form)!=null)
{
```